# Get subfile record number for non-active subfile(s)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a program that displays 4 subfiles similarly to this:

```
        COL1     COL2     COL3
SFLAA----------------------------|
    1    9999     9999     9999
    2    9999     9999     9999
    3    9999     9999     9999
                          *More...
SFLBB----------------------------|
    1    9999     9999     9999
    2    9999     9999     9999
    3    9999     9999     9999
                          *More...
SFLCC----------------------------|
    1    9999     9999     9999
    2    9999     9999     9999
    3    9999     9999     9999
                          *More...
SFLDD----------------------------|
    1    9999     9999     9999
    2    9999     9999     9999
    3    9999     9999     9999
                          *More...
```

These subfiles show various types of summary information and users want to be able to click on any of these summary numbers and "drill down" to the underlying details. In order to do that I have to know which record in which subfile they clicked on.

I'm retrieving the cursor location from the `INFDS` so when a user clicks on the screen I know which subfile they are clicking in (because I know what row they clicked on).

The `SFLCSRRRN` keyword works wonderfully for the `SFLAA` subfile because it's the "active" subfile (the program does an `EXFMT CTLAA`, all other control formats are displayed via `WRITE`). So far I have not been able to figure out how to determine which record of a subfile has been clicked on if it's `SFLBB`, `SFLCC` or `SFLDD`.

Each subfile holds up to ~100 records (all loaded at once) so it's possible (and likely) the user has scrolled the subfiles before clicking on them.

**How do I determine which subfile record the user clicked on if they click on one of the "non-active" subfiles?**

---- BEGIN EDIT ----

I can get the Row/Col of where the user clicked on the screen just fine, my problem is when the user scrolls SFLBB, SFLCC or SFLDD down to say the 75th subfile record and then they click on that subfile. I can tell they clicked on row 8 on the screen (this would be the first line of SFLBB) - but I can't tell that's record 75 in SFLBB.

---- END EDIT ----

I've tried `SFLCSRRRN`, `SFLRCDNBR`, and `SFLSCROLL` in various combinations and just cannot get anything to work for the non-active subfiles.

Here's relevant code from the `DSPF`:

```
A                                                    DSPSIZ(24 80 *DS3)
A                                                    MOUBTN(*ULP CF06)
A                        R SFLAA                     SFL
A                          RRN1           4Y 0O  4 11EDTCDE(Z)
A                        R CTLAA                     SFLCTL(SFLAA)
A                                                    SFLSIZ(9999)
A                                                    SFLPAG(0003)
A                                                    CF03
A                                                    OVERLAY
A                                                    SFLCSRRRN(&ARRN)
A  10                                                SFLDSP
A                                                    SFLDSPCTL
A N10                                                SFLCLR
A  11                                                SFLEND(*MORE)
A                          ARRN           5S 0H
A                                                3  2'SFLAA'
A                        R SFLBB                     SFL
A                          RRN2           4Y 0O  9 11EDTCDE(Z)
A                        R CTLBB                     SFLCTL(SFLBB)
A                                                    SFLSIZ(9999)
A                                                    SFLPAG(0003)
A                                                    OVERLAY
A* Doesn't work                                      SFLCSRRRN(&BRRN)
A  15                                                SFLDSP
A                                                    SFLDSPCTL
A N15                                                SFLCLR
A  16                                                SFLEND(*MORE)
A* Doesn't work            BRRN           5S 0H
A* Doesn't work            BRRN2          5S 0H      SFLSCROLL
A                                                8  2'SFLBB'
```

Subfiles and control records `SFLCC/CTLCC` and `SFLDD/CTLDD` are logically identical to `SFLBB/CTLBB` so I have omitted them.

Relevant RPGLE code:

```
ftestd              cf   e             workstn sfile(sflaa: rrn1)
f                                              sfile(sflbb: rrn2)
f                                              sfile(sflcc: rrn3)
f                                              sfile(sfldd: rrn4)
f                                              infds(cusloc)
...
dcusloc                    ds
d  rowcol                        370    371b 0
...
drrn1                      s              4  0 inz(0)
drrn2                      s              4  0 inz(0)
drrn3                      s              4  0 inz(0)
drrn4                      s              4  0 inz(0)
...
c/free
...
  begsr mouse_sr;
     row# = rowcol / 256;
     col# = %rem(rowcol: 256);
     select;
        when row# >= 4 and row# <= 6;
           chain arrn sflaa;
           if %found();
              exsr detail1_sr;
           endif;
        when row# >= 9 and row# <= 11;
           chain brrn sflbb;
           if %found();
              exsr detail2_sr;
           endif;
        when row# >= 14 and row# <= 16;
           chain crrn sflcc;
           if %found();
              exsr detail3_sr;
           endif;
        when row# >= 19 and row# <= 21;
           chain drrn sfldd;
           if %found();
              exsr detail4_sr;
           endif;
     endsl;
  endsr;
...
c/end-free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as posted had a typo (SFLBB overlaid SFLAA).  I added the little bit of glue to make it compile and ran it on IBM i 7.1.  My machine is current with PTFs.  Runs as expected.  Here is the complete code:

DDS:

```
 A                                      DSPSIZ(24 80 *DS3)
 A                                      MOUBTN(*ULP CF06)
 A          R SFLAA                     SFL
 A            RRN1           4Y 0O  4 11EDTCDE(Z)
 A          R CTLAA                     SFLCTL(SFLAA)
 A                                      SFLSIZ(9999)
 A                                      SFLPAG(0003)
 A                                      CF03(03)
 A                                      OVERLAY
 A                                      SFLCSRRRN(&ARRN)
 A  10                                  SFLDSP
 A                                      SFLDSPCTL
 A N10                                  SFLCLR
 A  11                                  SFLEND(*MORE)
 A            ARRN           5S 0H
 A                                  3  2'SFLAA'
 A          R SFLBB                     SFL
 A            RRN2           4Y 0O  9 11EDTCDE(Z)
 A          R CTLBB                     SFLCTL(SFLBB)
 A                                      SFLSIZ(9999)
 A                                      SFLPAG(0003)
 A                                      OVERLAY
 A* Doesn't work
 A                                      SFLCSRRRN(&BRRN)
 A  15                                  SFLDSP
 A                                      SFLDSPCTL
 A N15                                  SFLCLR
 A  16                                  SFLEND(*MORE)
 A            BRRN           5S 0H
 A* Doesn't work            BRRN2          5S 0H      SFLSCROLL
 A                                  8  2'SFLBB'
```

And RPG:

```
 fsotest    cf   e             workstn sfile(sflaa: rrn1)
 f                                     sfile(sflbb: rrn2)
 f                                     infds(cusloc)

 dcusloc           ds
 d  rowcol               370    371b 0

 drow#             s             10i 0 inz(0)
 dcol#             s             10i 0 inz(0)

 c/free

   *in10 = *off;  // SFLDSP AA
   *in15 = *off;  // SFLDSP BB
   write ctlbb;
   write ctlaa;
   *in10 = *on;  // SFLDSP AA
   *in15 = *on;  // SFLDSP BB

   for rrn1 = 1 to 5;
     rrn2 = rrn1;
     write sflaa;
     write sflbb;
   endfor;

   dow 1=1;
     write ctlbb;
     exfmt ctlaa;
     if *in03;
       *inlr = *on;
       leave;
     endif;
     exsr mouse_sr;
   enddo;

   begsr mouse_sr;
      row# = rowcol / 256;
      col# = %rem(rowcol: 256);

      select;
         when row# >= 4 and row# <= 6;
            chain arrn sflaa;
            if %found();
               // exsr detail1_sr;
            endif;
         when row# >= 9 and row# <= 11;
  ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE 
            read ctlbb;    // to get SFLRRN
            chain brrn sflbb;
            if %found();
               // exsr detail2_sr;
            endif;
      endsl;
   endsr;


  /end-free
```

I run it in debug and look at row# and col# at the SELECT and they always look OK.  See if you have the same results with this test code (both named SOTEST).  If this test code runs as expected, the problem in the production code probably isn't row/column.  If this test code exhibits incorrect row/column numbers, check your PTF levels.  If current, call it in as a bug.

**EDIT**: I misunderstood the problem.  RPG will fill in the I/O fields (like SFLCSRRRN)  from the control record only when the control record is READ.  The EXFMT handles this for CTLAA.  In order to handle it for the other control records, insert a READ inside the calculations where you've determined which subfile the user is in.

Comment: I'm sorry Buck, I failed to convey my problem. Getting the row/col is working fine. My problem is when a user scrolls SFLBB/CC/DD to (for instance) subfile record 75 and then clicks on the subfile. I can tell the user clicked on row X of the screen (which we will say is in SFLBB) but I can't determine which subfile record is currently being displayed.

Comment: Sorry Benny, my mistake not yours.  See my edit.  One needs to READ the control record format in order to get at the I/O fields (like SFLCSRRRN) in it.

Comment: Thanks Buck, that was it. After reading your comment it occurs to me that I've ran into a similar problem once before but had forgotten I needed to READ the other control record(s). Appreciate the help!